# Which APDU command should I use to cancel current reading record executing?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

When a host sends an APDU command to a card such as a read command, is there another command that the host could send while the first command is executed in order to cancel the previous (ongoing) command execution?

For instance, here Command_2 is interrupted by Command_3:

```
     Host        <--->        Card     
----------------------------------------------------------
 Command_1        --->             \
                                   | Processing Command_1
                 <---   Response_1 /

 Command_2        --->             \
                                   | Processing Command_2
                                   |
 Command_3        --->             x Processing interrupted
                 <---   Response_3 /
```

Comment: Is there anything I should add to my answer? If no, accept it, please.

Answer (score 5):

According to ISO/IEC 7816-4:2013 chapter 5.2:

> There must be no overlap of two Command APDU - Response APDU pairs on
>   the same interface, which means the response APDU must be received
>   before sending the next command APDU.

(Not the official version, the text above is my English translation from my language.)

Shortly speaking, there is no way to stop processing of the current APDU on application layer other than the warm reset, which is probably not what you want, because it resets the whole card (your applet is not selected anymore, RAM is cleared and persistent memory left untouched).